# How to grab the numebr with the end of "0" from the website?

Tags: python, html, python-re

I use BeaustifulSoup to grab some texts on the url"https://nature.altmetric.com/details/114136890",and get such response

```
# The table is called twitterGeographical_TableChoice
<table>
<tr>
<th>Country</th>
<th class="num">Count</th>
<th class="num percent">As %</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Japan</td>
<td class="num">3</td>
<td class="num">12%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Poland</td>
<td class="num">3</td>
<td class="num">12%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Spain</td>
<td class="num">3</td>
<td class="num">12%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>El Salvador</td>
<td class="num">2</td>
<td class="num">8%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ecuador</td>
<td class="num">1</td>
<td class="num">4%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mexico</td>
<td class="num">1</td>
<td class="num">4%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Chile</td>
<td class="num">1</td>
<td class="num">4%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>India</td>
<td class="num">1</td>
<td class="num">4%</td>
</tr>
<tr class="meta">
<td>Unknown</td>
<td class="num">10</td>
<td class="num">40%</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then I want to get the number from it.I use regular expression to get it.
My format is

```
twitterGeographical_Table_Num_pattern = re.compile('<td class=\"num\">(\d*%)</td>',re.S)
twitterGeographical_Table_Num = twitterGeographical_Table_Num_pattern.findall(twitterGeographical_TableChoice)
```

But I can only get 4% instead of 40%.I am puzzled.Thanks for your help!

Comment: _Then I want to get the number from it_... which number?

Comment: "I use regular expression to get it." - and now you have two problems... You are already using BeautifulSoup, why don't you use it to extract your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are going to get the numbers with the regex module when BeautifulSoup has already a lot of approaches for this. Anyway, if you are interested in regex you can use this pattern instead:

```
<td class=\"num\">((\d+)(%)?)</td>
```

Then you can get the numbers (percentages, if they are) using the code below:

```py
[x[0] for x in twitterGeographical_Table_Num]
```

##### Output

```
['10', '40%']
```

Side note: I beg you to consider naming the variables shorter and more clear!:)

Comment: Thanks you a lot!But it may be my fault that my extracted table was simplified before.I have updated my original table, and if you have any suggestions about BeautifulSoup , I am also glad to hear them. May you have a nice day!